# Referencing a 2nd function in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Still a javascript newbie here. I am in the process of creating a little script that displays the logged in user on the left of a grid and a set of images on the right. I have the HTML all setup as I need and have my logged in user functioning correctly.

My question is..

How do I get the function `loggiedinuser` to display the result into the Div tag `loggedinuser`. Below is my code.

Hopefully I have explained this correctly.

Thanks

Jack

```js
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
    .createTemplateFromFile('grids')
    .evaluate();
}

function loggedinuser() {

  var userEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var username = userEmail.substring(0, userEmail.indexOf("@"));
  var usernameUppercase = username.toUpperCase();

  var HTMLString = "<body> <h3> Logged in as " + usernameUppercase + "</h3></body>";


}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 80%;
}

.wrapper>div {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 1em;
}

.wrapper>div:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #ddd;
}

.apps ul {
  vertical-align: middle;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.apps li {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 14%;
}

.apps img {
  overflow: auto;
}

.apps img:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 30%;
}

.apps a {}
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <div class="wrapper">

    <div class="loggedin">


    </div>

    <div class="apps">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="https://mail.google.com/a/">
            <img border="0" alt="Gmail" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1UXYyAO52U3kY4oVYYpaY__Z8kN8VHFxN" width="40" height="40">
          </a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="https://drive.google.com/a/">
            <img border="0" alt="Google Drive" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1I53gryIOd2-PYtINtLDjY_SNjzw3AP1w" width="40" height="40">
          </a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="https://www.google.com/calendar/hosted/">
            <img border="0" alt="Google Calendar" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=18ZLAHw-ygNpPB6ykZV8zVjap1qcyAmuY" width="40" height="40">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="https://classroom.google.com">
            <img border="0" alt="Google Classroom" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1oHMpEX8HKNxIOgOY12N_VTrqc3PdX654" width="40" height="40">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <img class="appsicon" border="0" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=17wU1CyojZMixcv6g3j5mKBnFbs_JCkGL" onclick="myFunction()" width="40" height="40">
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: When you call the function from the client side code, give it a success handler. The return value of the called function is passed to the success handler (and a throw exception is passed to the designated failure handler). In the success handler, use the return value as desired. See the examples in Apps Script documentation for `google.script.run`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<div class="loggedin">
    <?!= loggedinuser() ?>
</div>

function loggedinuser() {
  var userEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var username = userEmail.substring(0, userEmail.indexOf("@"));
  var usernameUppercase = username.toUpperCase();
  return "<body> <h3> Logged in as " + usernameUppercase + "</h3></body>";
}
```